# Let a fixed div grow to width 100% by Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some jquery support, because my js skills are very low ;(. I have found and modified a script, that slides a div out to the right (relative div), but the fixed div dont grow up to width 100% when the relative div slides out.

What´s the plan?

If I press "click here" the relative div should slide out and at the same time the fixed div should morph to width 100%. So if I press "Click here" again, the relative div slides back into his position and the fixed div should morph back to width 70% (same time).

Thats my script - can you modified it?

```
 $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            var $menu = $('.relative_div');
            if ($menu.is(':visible')) {
                // Slide away
                $menu.animate({right: -($menu.outerWidth() + 50)}, function() {
                    $menu.hide();
                });
            }
            else {
                // Slide in
                $menu.show().animate({right: 0});
            }
        });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/efst0n17/)

I would be very grateful.

Snatch

Comment: Why did you ignore the message that you have to post the code here?

Comment: Ok, now I understand the logic behind the message - I thought I have to press "STRG + K" around the fiddle URL - my fail, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

`$('.fixed_div').animate({width: '100%'});` when you want to expand the div

and

`$('.fixed_div').animate({width: '70%'});` when you want to short the div

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efst0n17/3/)

Comment: Thats exact what i am looking for - thank you guys!!

Comment: Aslo, take a look at the http://velocityjs.org/. jQuery's animate is not the best performer since it is based on timeouts, by including library that I have linked to you animate will be using requestAnimationFrame and an overall performance of you animation will improve significantly.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/efst0n17/4/
```

added

```
 $('.fixed_div').css("width","100%");
```

and

```
$('.fixed_div').css("width","70%");
```

Fixed for you!